# REST API show items if current logged in user's department is not equal to other user's department

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api, user-profile

How can write logic in REST API if current user login is from department XX-YYZ-AB or ZZ-YYZ and I have another list with list of people with different departments, so how shall I exclude users in my REST call so if I am from XX-YYZ-AB shall exclude all users who fall under XX-YY same goes for if my login department is ZZ-YYZ it exclude all user in my REST call who falls under ZZ-YY.

**for ex**

Login User Dept AA-XXV

And other users department

AA-XXV

AA-XXV-GG

AA-XX

AA

So it should only show AA after filter in rest api is it possible other should exclude ?

Comment: are you able to get the user department?

Comment: yes i can get department

Comment: Please mark the question as answered if it has answered your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve the results using two API calls.

I have created a 'TestDL' list having 'TestPerson' column of type Person.
You need to use two rest API

1. first API to get the department of logged in user. Suppose the logged in User Department is IT
2. Call another API and pass the Department name that you got in 1st API call.

> https://site_url/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('TestDL')/items?$select=TestPerson/Title,TestPerson/EMail,TestPerson/Department&$expand=TestPerson&$filter=TestPerson/Department
> eq 'IT'

It will give you result of people 'TestPerson' column who are in IT depatment.